# How to query data from server-side with Extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4, server-side, extjs4.1

I just started to learn Extjs，and want to realize a server-side query。I have wrote some code like this in my Contriller of Extjs MVC：

```
'SearchPanel button[action=select]': {
                'click' : function() {
                    //console.log(Ext.getDom('s_name').value );
                    console.log(Ext.getCmp('s_studentid').getValue());
                    var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('studentList')[0];
                    var store  = grid.store;

                    store.filterBy(function(record) {
                        //return record.get('name') == '张新武' && record.get('id') == 8;
                        var s_studentid = Ext.getCmp('s_studentid').getValue();
                        var s_name = Ext.getCmp('s_name').getValue();
                        var s_unikey = Ext.getCmp('s_unikey').getValue();
                        var s_type = Ext.getCmp('s_type').getValue();
                        var s_sex = Ext.getCmp('s_sex').getValue();
                        var s_college = Ext.getCmp('s_college').getValue();
                        var s_major = Ext.getCmp('s_major').getValue();
                        var s_ethnic = Ext.getCmp('s_ethnic').getValue();
                        return (s_studentid == "" || record.get('id') == s_studentid)
                            &&(s_name == "" || record.get('name').indexOf(s_name)>=0)
                            &&(s_unikey == "" || record.get('name') == s_unikey)
                            &&(s_type == "" || record.get('type') == s_type)
                            &&(s_sex == "" || record.get('sex') == s_sex)
                            &&(s_college == "" || record.get('college') == s_college)
                            &&(s_major == "" || record.get('major') == s_major)
                            &&(s_ethnic == "" || record.get('ethnic') == s_ethnic);
                        console.log('invoke select');
                    });
                }  
            }
```

But I found it query data from the Extjs store,not from the server-side.How do I change my code that it can query data from server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload with a new paramset in order to realize server-side filtering

```
store.load({params: /* all this stuff */})
```

or similar..

Comment: But it must be many params,such as s_name,s_unikey,s_type and so on,how to Passes these parameters to the server-side.sorry,I'm a rookie，maybe this question is pretty stupid.

Comment: Look at http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.AbstractStore and http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Operation

Comment: thank you.now I passe these parameters to the server-side.and my url is like this:http://localhost:8080/soft-enrol/student?_dc=1344085932402&s_studentid=6&s_name=&s_unikey=&s_type=&s_sex=&s_college=&s_major=&s_ethnic=&page=1&start=0&limit=3.  it's not a restful url.I want to got a url like this:http://localhost:8080/soft-enrol/student/query.How do I do that？

Comment: POST is "CREATE" in RESTFul,but my operate is "SELECT"，Would it not follow restful norms.

Comment: Then stay at GET, these are called _query_ parameters, it's RESTful.